# C++ QtNetworkRequest download image but got HTML

Tags: c++, image, qt, download

i have this link

> http://www.deviantart.com/download/425078223/dota2__wraith_night_by_phsueh-d712wgf.jpg?token=58443eec715f93cd984f8e4f03e287cce3cff717&ts=1390123417

i paste it into my browser then got an image.
but when i'm coding to download this, i got some HTML code, here it is:

```
<html><head><title>Redirection</title></head><body><script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="http:\/\/phsueh.deviantart.com\/art\/DOTA2-Wraith-Night-425078223"</script><noscript><a href="http://phsueh.deviantart.com/art/DOTA2-Wraith-Night-425078223">Click here to continue.</a></noscript></body></html>
```

can anyone tell me how to get actual image that the link point to.

p/s: i follow this tutorial http://www.java2s.com/Code/Cpp/Qt/DownloadfromURL.htm

Comment: Try to paste link: http://fc07.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2014/006/c/3/dota2__wraith_night_by_phsueh-d712wgf.jpg

Comment: but how to get that link. i mean, in this art http://phsueh.deviantart.com/art/DOTA2-Wraith-Night-425078223, the biggest image place right on the page. but some others, we must click on the download button and get the image(the biggest image)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to request the art page first to save the cookie `userinfo` and get the individual download link (containing token and timestamp) the page gave you. It could be found with a string search for the download button element and extracting the `href` value.

```
<a class="dev-page-button dev-page-button-with-text dev-page-download"
```

Now you just have to send a request for that individual download link with the saved cookie and you will be redirected to your image.